# Conditional for checking if a function has returned HTML markup

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a conditional statement which when true displays some `<nav>` markup which inside has a [paginate_comments_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) function which returns html links to pages containing comments.

```
<?php
if( ( $is_comments_pagination == true ) ) { ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'prev_text' => '&larr;',
            'next_text' => '&rarr;',
            'type'      => 'list',
        );
        paginate_comments_links($args);
        ?>
    </nav>
<?php } ?>
```

This works - but if there are no pages of comments then the `<nav>` markup will remain. If there are no pages of comments I don't want the `<nav>` markup.

However I can't seem to figure out how to check if paginate_comments_links is returning the markup and using that in the conditional.

I have tried:

```
if( ( $is_comments_pagination == true ) && ( paginate_comments_links() ) ) { ?>
```

This executes the function straight away where shown, I have also tried:

```
if( ( $is_comments_pagination == true ) && ( isset(paginate_comments_links()) ) ) { ?>
```

The debugger then tells me to instead check if the function is null, but the function exists - it just may not return anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sir MacPotato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831928/227299) works, but I think `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` are kind of dirty hacks.

You have the option to call `paginate_comments_links(array('echo' => false))` and the code will not automatically echo the content, the HTML is returned as a string and you can echo it yourself. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links#Return_Values

```
if (($is_comments_pagination == true)) {
    $args = array(
        'prev_text' => '&larr;',
        'next_text' => '&rarr;',
        'type'      => 'list',
        'echo'      => false
    );
    $content = paginate_comments_links($args);
    if (strlen($content) > 0)) {
        echo "<nav class=\"pagination\">$content</nav>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I overlooked the 'echo' true/false arguments, this will work great now - thanks.

Comment: Yup, a bit dirty indeed. I haven't checked for docs about the ```paginate_comments_links``` function, and in the hurry I assumed that it'll echo the pagination *(Dirty things i'm used to see, sadly...)*.

All credits for you ;)

Comment: @SirMcPotato To be honest, I've never touched a line of code with wordpress, it's just common for functions that call `echo` to have the option not to output anything and return it instead. I just tweaked what you suggested, that's why I made sure to give you credit

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `paginate_comments_links($args);` will directly `echo` the pagination content.
So you can use [Output Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to put the result of your function in a buffer, get the buffer content and then check if empty.
If you have some content to display, wrap it between your nav tag and display it.

```
if (($is_comments_pagination == true)) {
    $args = array(
        'prev_text' => '&larr;',
        'next_text' => '&rarr;',
        'type'      => 'list',
    );
    ob_start();
    paginate_comments_links($args);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    if (strlen($content) > 0)) {
        echo "<nav class=\"pagination\">$content</nav>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this and it does indeed work fine, it is a great answer however I am going to use Juan Mendes' solution as it seems a cleaner way to do it (as it's just tweaking the existing output). But thanks anyway :)